# How to take even 'NULL' and '' as input for a OBIEE prompt?

Tags: null, default, prompt, obiee

Is it possible to consider the text NULL and '' as input to the OBIEE prompt? I have a column with a default value. If a user removes that and then submits the query, a report should return nothing for that prompt condition. Instead, the default OBIEE takes the condition as 'column is like '%''. Even for NULL text as input, the backend query is formed as 'column is not null'. Is there a way around for this? Could you please give a detailed explanation? I am new to this.

I have tried it with the column area but no luck so far.

NA

NA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply configure the prompt as "Require user input" and not allow free text? It's an analytical platform and not google ;-)